# Tableau: How to display two distinct columns in worksheet, but in the filter concatenate the two columns

Tags: tableau-api

For example, I show two columns--CustNumber and CustName.  In a filter, I would like to concatenate the two values something like this:

```
10100  My Customer
```

This would allow the user to enter either the customer number OR some of the customer's name in drop-down filter to filter by.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, please provide a sample dataset which would help us to get a better understanding on to help you the best.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a separate calculated field to use as the filter.

`CustNumberName` =

```
STR([CustNumber]) + ' ' + [CustName]
```

`CustNumberName` can then be used as a filter (presumably set to Wildcard Match) and the existing 2 columns can stay in the pane.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a calculated field as G Hart states.

You can also create a combined field, by selecting multiple dimensions in the data pane and right clicking to Create->Combined Field. The combined field behaves very similar to a calculated field in most respects and you can easily change the delimiter or field order.

There are a few restrictions with combined fields. They can’t be used in most (or all?) calculations, nor to populate the list of possible values for a parameter. But they are easy and convenient otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the additional tip.  I will think I like the idea of Combined field better.  I will check it out too... Thank you.